# Android Espresso failing for key event error

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have an Espresso test that tests for a successful pin entry.  The test enters some keys on the keypad and then the activity finishes successfully.  After the keys are entered I am getting an espresso error even though the behaviour in the test is as expected.  Can anyone help?

Test Code

```
@Test
public void shouldSuccessfullyEnterPin() {
    onView(isRoot())
            .perform(pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1),
                    pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2),
                    pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3),
                    pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4));

    assertTrue(mActivityRule.getActivity().isFinishing());
}
```

Error

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'send keyCode: 11, metaState: 0 key event' on view 'is a root view.'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at net.weareact.mobile.collection.saltirecard.cloudpostclient.activity.ui.PinEntryActivityTest.shouldSuccessfullyEnterPin(PinEntryActivityTest.java:65)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectKeyEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:121)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.EventInjector.injectKeyEvent(EventInjector.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$2.call(UiControllerImpl.java:186)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl$2.call(UiControllerImpl.java:183)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at android.hardware.input.IInputManager$Stub$Proxy.injectInputEvent(IInputManager.java:356)
at android.hardware.input.InputManager.injectInputEvent(InputManager.java:641)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.injectKeyEvent(InputManagerEventInjectionStrategy.java:112)
... 9 more
```